# What should be a string, "Punch", is being treated as integer

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a text-based adventure game. Currently, I am making a battle sequence where one of the actions is "Punch". It should be a string through and through, but Python is saying it's an integer.

I've tried to use a str(input()) (the user types Punch for the input) to try and force it to be a string, but to no avail. I am still a beginner Python user, so this is really all I can think of.

```
def battle1():
    print('''You walk out of the dungeon and start
    down the hallway. As you walk, a Chaos Wizard turns
    the corner and blocks you! You engage in battle with
    the wizard.''')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Your HP: 15/15')
    print('Wizard\'s HP: 15/15')
    time.sleep(3)
    battlephase()
def battlephase():
    playerHealth = 15
    wizardHealth = 15
    punchdamage = random.randint(1, 3)
    daggerdamage = random.randint(1, 5)
    dartdamage = random.randint(4, 7)
    while action == 'Punch' or action == 'Dagger' or action == 'Help Potion' or action == 'Poison Dart':
        if action == 'Punch':
            print('You sock the Chaos Wizard right in the jaw! ' + punchdamage + 'damage!')
            wizardHealth = wizardHealth - punchdamage
            wizardAttack()
```

When I or a user inputs Punch, it should print the player taking the action and dealing damage to the enemy and continuing on normally. Instead, typing punch results in the error: "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly".

Comment: Please show the code that's getting user input.

Comment: This code doesn;t initialize the `action` variable. Please also include the full error traceback

Comment: Use some kind of IDE to program. You should be getting the line where the code fails, which should point you sooner in the right direction. By the likes, my bet is `punchdamage`, not `action` as you are assuming.

Answer (score 1):

By the likes, my bet is `punchdamage`, not `action` as you are assuming.

In the print function with `+`, python cannot cast automatically `int` to `str` type implicitly (as your error states). Therefore you need to explicitly convert to str your punchdamage

```
print('You sock the Chaos Wizard right in the jaw! ' + str(punchdamage) + 'damage!')
```

or to pass print several parameters

```
print('You sock the Chaos Wizard right in the jaw!', punchdamage, 'damage!')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [f strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) or [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) rather than concatenation.

In 3.6+, you can do this:

```py
print(f'You sock the Chaos Wizard right in the jaw! {punchdamage} damage!')
```

And before you can do this:

```py
print('You sock the Chaos Wizard right in the jaw! {} damage!'.format(punchdamage))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 print('You sock the Chaos Wizard right in the jaw! ' + str(punchdamage) + ' damage!')
```

Comment: You can't add strings and integers, which is his exact problem.  Did you mean `str(punchdamage)`?

Comment: Sorry, sure. Corrected.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answer with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and more likely to attract upvotes.